# phalcon selectStatic default value

Tags: phalcon, volt

are there other ways to set a default value for selectStatic tag in PhalconPHP other than setting it in the controller using

```
$this->tag->setDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can add this to your services
- You can add this to base controller's initialize() function and all your controllers must extend this base controller.